# Google maps api v3  фиксировать положение и масштаб карты

Tags: google-maps-api

Народ, подскажите как сделать, чтобы пользователь не мог изменить масштаб карты и не мог ее двигать

Answer (score 2):

```
var mapOptions = {  
    zoom: 4,  
    minZoom: 4,
    maxZoom: 4,
    draggable:false
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    mapOptions);
```